# Drawing rectangles with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, draw

I have a div called #llens where I need to draw some boxes ( div's). I can't understand why is not drawing. I'm a litle newbie so please be patient if I'm make a great mistakes :P

that's the div :

```
  <div id="estructura" class="collapse ">
    <section data-toggle="buttons-radio" class="btn-group btn-group-vertical">
        <header id="professor" class="btn btn-primary boto_funcio ">
             <h2>Professors</h2> 
        </header>
        <header id="alumne" class="btn btn-primary boto_funcio ">
             <h2>Alumnes   </h2> 
        </header>
        <header id="text" class="btn btn-primary boto_funcio ">
             <h2>Text      </h2> 
        </header>
    </section>
</div>
<section class="span9">
    <div id="llens"></div>
    <!-- llens -->
</section>
```

**Here is the example :** http://jsfiddle.net/blackersoul/PLWkS/

I 've done a fork from  the code there : http://jsfiddle.net/lollero/kDmqw/

Comment: if you want to close (remove) rectangles, see the following fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ur2qrgw7/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes a html element is not displayed when it is empty. Try `<div id="llens">&nbsp;</div>`.

Comment: Németh   it is displayed, if you take a look to the example you'll see a grid that's the background's #llens ...

Comment: Blackersoul - `'<div class="casella ' + opcio + '">'` This is the div you want to draw on llens?

Comment: These divs have 0px height. When I edit the css to have 10px height I can see them.